# Python - Increasing number from the number that is stored in a text file

Tags: python

```
accountNum = open("data/accountNum.txt","r")
str_size = accountNum.read()
size = int(str_size)
accountNum.close()
```

At the beginning of the code, I read a text file called accountNum.

This is for getting the number stored in a text file, and I want to know how to increase the number that is stored in the text file. There is only one number stored, which indicates the number of accounts registered.

For example, I have 3 accounts registered, so when I read it, it should print 3. However, as I add one more account, I have to change the number from 3 to 4. To use write, I have no idea how to get the number and add 1 (+1) because I keep getting errors such as int converting str error or str converting int error.

I need to open accountNum and change the number stored in the text file by adding 1 per each trial.

Comment: what code have you written to write to the file?

Comment: Please specify what doesn't work, is it incrementing the number, simply converting the data from the file to an int or writing the modified value into the file?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new file with the same name so that it will overwrite `accountNum.txt`:

```
with open("data/accountNum.txt", 'r') as f:
   str_size = f.read()
   size = int(str_size)
   with open('data/accountNum.txt', 'w') as f2:
      f2.write(str(size+1))
```

*Note: i did `with open` because i think it's easier you don't need to add an extra line to close it*